# How to use XYZ tiles from zoom 11 to a higher zoom

Tags: qgis, tiles, mapping, zoom, xyz

I have generated my own map tiles for zoom 11 (only). I display these tiles in QGIS via XYZ tiles (as a new connection - file:///D:/tiles/11/{x}/{y}.png). They show up fine for the zoom 11.

However, I would like to use them for the zoom 12 as well, with the fact that they will be stretched. How do I achive this in QGIS, please? Tiles from zoom 11 are not showing for zoom 12 for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the layer properties, limit the maximum zoom to 11 level.

[image]

**Attention!** This may not work in the layer properties because the URL disappears (some QGIS glitch). You must re-enter the XYZ URL, on the same "Source" layer properties tab.

P.S. You can also limit the minimum zoom to 11 so that your XYZ layer is always visible.

Comment: This works great. Thank you! It also helps me to editing the connection base on your answer before adding to layers (it didn't work when editing in layers).

Comment: @Lubor Yes, it might not work in the layer properties because the URL disappears (some QGIS glitch). You must re-enter the XYZ URL, on the same "Source" layer properties tab. It helped me.