# Difficulty reading standard OpenStreetMap labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, font

Standard OpenStreetMap labels are too small to read. TIFF they are scaling with zoom, they become for a second large, then go back to tiny, less than 4 points size.

What can be done? Is it a settings? Font Scaling? Raster image property?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use XYZ tiles from zoom 11 to a higher zoom](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/464042/how-to-use-xyz-tiles-from-zoom-11-to-a-higher-zoom)

Answer (score 2):

OSM tiles are defined at specific scales. If you happen to display them at the wrong scale, they are zoomed-out until you reach the next scale level.

Fortunately, you can easily fix this by right clicking the layer and opting to `zoom to native resolution`

Example at a wrong scale:
[image]

After fixing the resolution:
[image]

Comment: Plus EPSG:3857 as native CRS for the tiles